# How do I make a column under customer that references "id" from the employer table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
CREATE TABLE College (
    CollegeID INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    Collegename varchar(50),
    PRIMARY KEY(CollegeID));

INSERT INTO `College` (`CollegeID`, `Collegename`) VALUES
(1, 'Harvard'),
(2, 'Princeton'),
(3, 'Columbia'),
(4, 'Georgetown'),
(5, 'Yale');



 CREATE TABLE Customer (
    CustomerID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    FirstName varchar(20),
    LastName varchar(20),
    DateHired DATE,
    CollegeID INTEGER REFERENCES College(CollegeID));



INSERT INTO `Customer` (`CustomerID`, `FirstName`, `LastName`, `DateHired`, `CollegeID`) VALUES
(111, 'Johnny', 'Silvia', '20100301', 1),
(222, 'Billy', 'Blank', '20070111', 2),
(333, 'Susan', 'Anderson', '20021222', 3),
(444, 'Samantha', 'Love', '19990521', 3),
(555, 'Bill', 'Gray', '20010913', 5);



CREATE TABLE `employer` (
  `id` INTEGER NOT NULL,
  `EmployerName` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(id));


INSERT INTO `employer` (`id`, `EmployerName`) VALUES
(1111, 'McDonalds');
```

Comment: Don't delete [the same question previously you asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13719420/sql-database-adding-table) to bump your question. This may cause you post ban.

Comment: I was told my question was not clear so I thought I could redo it, my mistake

Comment: The you needed to *edit* your question not *adding* a question

Answer (score 0):

If a customer can have one but only one employer, then yes, add the employer id reference into your customer table.

If a customer can have more than one employer, then you have to create another table that contains Ids of customers and Ids of employers.

```
 CREATE TABLE Customer (
    CustomerID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    EmployerID INTEGER REFERENCES employer(id),
    FirstName varchar(20),
    LastName varchar(20),
    DateHired DATE,
    CollegeID INTEGER REFERENCES College(CollegeID));
```

I don't know mysql well, I just took the syntax you used, but if you want to create foreign key references check this link out http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about `FOREIGN KEYs`

To create `FOREIGN KEYs` on your table/s:

```
/* Create the Parent Table */
CREATE TABLE College (
    ID INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    CollegeName VARCHAR(50),
    PRIMARY KEY(ID)
);

/* Create the Child Table and Referece the Column CollegeId of this table to the Id Column of College Table */
CREATE TABLE Customer (
    ID INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    Name VARCHAR(40),
    CollegeID INT(11),
    PRIMARY KEY(ID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Customer_College FOREIGN KEY (CollegeID) REFERENCES College (ID)
);
```

Follow this syntax:
`CONSTRAINT ForeignKeyName FOREIGN KEY (ColumnName) REFERENCES TableName (ColumnName)`

On the other hand, if you have already created the tables, you can just create the `FOREIGN KEY` by altering the table:

`ALTER ChildTable ADD CONSTRAINT ForeignKeyName FOREIGN KEY (ChildColumn) REFERENCES ParentTable (ParentColumn);`